# Binding a collection of blog items to view using Knockout JS in MVC 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a scenario of displaying a collection of blog post in my view which is a asp.net MVC 5 application. I am not able to iterate my collection on the view in order to display the list of blog post.

My code follows,

The Model class

```
public class Blogs
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string BlogName { get; set; }
    public string SmallDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The Collection Class

```
 public class BlogCollection
{
    public List<Blogs> GetLatestBlogs()
    {
        var blogs = new List<Blogs>();

        var blog1 = new Blogs
        {
            BlogId = 1,
            BlogName = "Alice in Wonderland, part dos",
            SmallDescription = " You ought to be ashamed of yourself for asking such a simple question" +
            "added the Gryphon; and then they both sat silent and looked at poor Alice, who felt ready to sink into the earth. " +
            "At last the Gryphon said to the Mock Turtle,  Drive on, old fellow! Don t be all day about it!  and he went on in these words:" +
                                 "Yes, we went to school in the sea, though you mayn t believe it— " +
                                 "I never said I didn t!  interrupted Alice." +
                                 "You did,  said the Mock Turtle.",
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
            Tags = new List<string> { 
                "WPF", "MVC", "MVVM"
            }
        };
        var blog2 = new Blogs
        {
            BlogId = 5,
            BlogName = "Revolution has begun! ",
            SmallDescription = "  if you are using javascript to post the list of tags you may be much more interested in tag manage API, see below how to retrieve the list of tags entered by the user using the API or how to have tag manager automatically push the tags to a ajax location.",
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
            Tags = new List<string> { 
                "SQL", "SSIS", "SSAS"
            }
        };
        blogs.Add(blog1);
        blogs.Add(blog2);
        return blogs;
    }
}
```

}

The client side viewmodel javascript

```
    BlogViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
};
```

Finally the view where I want to list the posts,

```
@model IEnumerable<TestApplication.Models.Blogs>
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
@{string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);}
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/BlogViewModel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var blogViewModel = new BlogViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));

        ko.applyBindings(blogViewModel);
    </script>
}



<div class="well well-sm">
    <div class="tabbable-panel">

        <div class="tabbable-line">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#tab_default_trends" data-toggle="tab">
                        Its Trending!
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_default_trends">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: blogViewModel">
                            <h3>
                                <a href="#" class="btn-link" data-bind="text: BlogName">

                                </a>
                            </h3>
                            <p data-bind="text: SmallDescription">

                            </p>
                            <div>
                                <span class="badge" data-bind="text: CreationDate"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code runs fine but without any data.

Comment: When you view the page source, is the data being correctly rendered in the page? Could you post the JSON?

Comment: looking like working for me check here http://jsfiddle.net/HTm8z/299/ . cheers

Comment: I am returning a list of blogs from controller
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var blogCollections = new Models.BlogCollection().GetLatestBlogs();
            return View(blogCollections);
        }

Comment: I am using Javascript serializer instead.

Comment: `new BlogViewModel(@Html.Raw(data))` what you getting at this line .

Comment: var blogViewModel = new BlogViewModel([{"BlogId":1,"BlogName":"Alice in Wonderland, part dos","SmallDescription":" You ought to beent to school in the sea, tTurtle.","CreationDate":"\/Date(1427878807195)\/","Tags":["WPF","MVC","MVVM"]},{"BlogId":5,"BlogName":"Revolution has begun! ","SmallDescription":"  if you are using javascript to post the list location.","CreationDate":"\/Date(1427878807195)\/","Tags":["SQL","SSIS","SSAS"]}]);

Comment: Clipped some text of SmallDescription to support max character support of SO.

Comment: @supercool With your Code its working fine but how will you map the child list i.e. the tags inside the parent list blog as no mapping is defined.

Comment: try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/HTm8z/300/ . Hope it clarifies everything .